# Spherical perverse sheaves on the affine Grassmannian and critically twisted $D$-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, geometric-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group and let $Gr_G=G((z))/G[[z]]$ be its affine Grassmannian. Define $\mathcal{D}(Gr_G)_{crit}-mod$ to be the category of right $D$-modules on $Gr_G$ twisted by the critical level of $G$ (which is $-1/2$ the Killing form).

In [this paper](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v170-n3-p07-p.pdf) of Frenkel-Gaitsgory it is mentioned on page $1347$ that there is an equivalence 
$$\mathcal{D}(Gr_G)_{crit}-mod^{G[[z]]} \cong Rep(G^{\vee})$$
between the category of $G[[z]]$ equivariant critically twisted $D$-modules on $Gr_G$ and representations of the Langlands dual. I'm a little bit confused since the geometric Satake equivalence is phrased most often using $G[[z]]$-equivariant perverse sheaves on $Gr_G$, and not $D$-modules.

By Riemann-Hilbert, I know that perverse sheaves are related to regular holonomic $D$-modules, but I fail to see how this gives us the equivalence of categories written above. Does anyone have a quick explanation of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The critical shift can be eliminated by twisting w.r.t. a cetain line bundle. Then the only fact to note is that the D-modules on the LHS are automatically regular holonomic - see e.g. 11.6 of Hotta-Takeuchi-Tanisaki for this (technically they do it only in the finite-dimensional case, but it is easy to deduce what you want from that). In general I think the resolution to these issues is more transparent to see in the Beilinson-Bernstein context, so maybe thinking about that first may be helpful.

Comment: @dhy Thank you! I didn’t know that things on the LHS are already regular holonomic so this is perfect